# stackdriver not monitoring kafka metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to setup kafka metrics on stackdriver. I followed all steps as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/kafka , but still cant see "kafka" metrics. Although I can see metrics of Host, Agent, Zookeeper and JVM

I can also see the metrics from kafka's script:
`bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.JmxTool --object-name 'kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec' --jmx-url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9
999/jmxrmi`

Result of above script:
`"time","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:Count","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:EventType","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FifteenMin
uteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FiveMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:MeanRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:
OneMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:RateUnit"
1546947405966,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
1546947407959,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
1546947409963,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS`

Comment: Are you looking for the metrics (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-kafka) in Metrics Explorer? If not, where? What's the VM image?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the best forum for reporting such issues — it's a question/answer platform. You would get a better response if you re-send your report to google-stackdriver-discussion@googlegroups.com .

That said, what version of Kafka are you using? The instructions on that web page only apply to versions close to 0.8.2 (i.e., 1.* should work, but 2.* may not).